# match email and confirm

Tags: javascript

I would like to match email address with the confirm email address. I have tried this validation but it's not working. Don't know why.

```
function ValidationRequired(field, alerttxt){

    with (field){

        if (value==null || value==""){
            alert(alerttxt);
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}


function ValidateThisForm(thisform){

    with(thisform){
        if(ValidationRequired(EmailAddress, "You must supply an e-Mail address.") == false){
            EmailAddress.focus();return false;
        }
    }
    with(thisform){
        if(ValidationRequired(EmailAddressConfirm, "You must confirm your e-Mail address.") == false){
            EmailAddressConfirm.focus();return false;
        }
    }    

    with(thisform){
        if(ValidationRequired(EmailAddress != EmailAddressConfirm, "Those emails don\'t match!") == false){
            EmailAddressConfirm.focus();return false;
        }
    }

    return true;    
}
```

Comment: How does it not work? Provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter to the function `ValidationRequired` is supposed to be a field. In the code that is supposed to match the email addresses, the first parameter is *not* a field, but a boolean expression.

```
with(thisform){
    if(ValidationRequired(EmailAddress != EmailAddressConfirm, "Those emails don\'t match!") == false){
        EmailAddressConfirm.focus();return false;
    }
}
```

You could solve this in a few different ways. One way would be to write a second validation function that takes two field parameters and compares the values of two fields.

But if you want to know why the code isn't working, it's because your not passing a field to the function.